# Can I undo a checkout FETCH_HEAD?

Tags: git

I accidentally overwritten unstaged files on server by:

```
git fetch origin [branch_name]
git checkout FETCH_HEAD -- [branch_name]
```

Comment: Then your changes are lost

Comment: One possible lifeline would be if your IDE has its own history for the files you had changed in the working directory.  I have gotten away with a lot in the past using this trick.

Answer (score 1):

Your changes are lost. To avoid these situations in the future, use git stash before making moves that you are not sure of.